# Generate binaries for executing C# Visual Studio script in Linux

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cross-platform

this might be a very stupid question but I was asked to provide a solution of a C# code that I wrote in Visual Studio together with "binaries" to run on a Linux or MacOS system.

How can I generate these binaries and how do they work? Does Visual Studio have some option to make them?

Comment: Why is this tagged c++? What runtime is the c# code targeting?

Comment: Oops, sorry I removed the tag. As for runtime, does that refer to the NET framework? In my settings I have .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: A "binary" is generally an executable file that is created by compiling. When you build the C# code that you wrote, what file gets created? Can you run that file to execute your code? That is your binary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target .NET Core, then you can run it on all major operating systems (with some limitations - i.e. there can't be any WPF or Winforms code). Select ".NET 5.0" as target framework. Then right-click the project in VS and choose "Publish". It's easiest to choose "Publish to folder" afterwards. In the options, you can choose the target operating system.

Comment: I see! Thanks, with your instructions I was able to do it.

Comment: One more question @PMF, what if my project uses DllImport for an external dll dependency? It seems just putting the dll in the same folder as the published binary is not enough. I get Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException

Comment: @HTSS : That's a quite unrelated question, but generally that should work, also with .NET Core. You might need to make sure any further dependencies of that external DLL are also available. (The exception you get may not point to the file that's actually missing)

Comment: Oh, and external DLLs are typically native, so you can't move them between operating systems.